# Java jar problem

Tags: java, jar, classpath

My knowledge of Java is rather rusty, but I've been forced to use it and am having some terrible classpath troubles...

I'm trying to import a jwebserver class. It should be straightforward, but I don't know how!

Here is my server.java file:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.jWebSocket.*;

public class server
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}
```

And here is the error when I try to compile:

```
>>> javac -classpath ./libs/jWebSocketServer-0.9.5.jar server.java 
server.java:2: package org.jWebSocket does not exist
import org.jWebSocket.*;
^
1 error
```

Here is an ls output:

```
>>> ls
bin  conf  libs  logs  server.java
```

and here is an ls ./libs output:

```
>>> ls ./libs
commons-lang-2.5.jar
javolution-5.5.1.jar
json-2-RELEASE65.jar
jWebSocketAdmin-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketCluster-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketCore-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketCustomServer-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketFactory-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketNettyEngine-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketPlugins-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketSamples-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketServer-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketSharedObjects-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketTCPEngine-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketTokenServer-0.9.5.jar
jWebSocketToolkit-0.9.5.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
netty-3.2.0.BETA1.jar
servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.5.10.jar
```

I'm hoping someone can help me here.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you sure "jWebSocketServer-0.9.5.jar" was downloaded correctly? Maybe it was corrupted. Since Jar file are the same as zip file, check to see if the file is ok by opening it in a Zip tool (7-zip for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick look at jWebSocket, the problem might just be case sensitivity in your package name.

Try `import org.jwebsocket.*;`

That should get your code to compile. Getting it to do something useful, on the other hand... :) try the JavaDocs on the website (the Java/JS Docs link on the [jWebSocket website](http://jwebsocket.org/))

---

Update: There's nothing actually in the package org.jwebsocket. There is a class in org.jwebsocket.console, so try `import org.jwebsocket.console.*;`

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for that.

I tried changing the case and it didn't work: same error...

Comment: There are no classes in org.jwebsocket - the only class in the .jar is in org.jwebsocket.console. Try import org.jwebsocket.console.*

Answer (score 2):

jWebSocketServer-0.9.5.jar probably depends on jWebSocketCore.0.9.5.jar. So you need to add them both in the classpath command:

```
javac -classpath ./libs/jWebSocketServer-0.9.5.jar;./libs/jWebSocketCore-0.9.5.jar; server.java
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply. I tried that and it didn't work. Same error ;(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all jars on your `libs` folder to your compilation classpath:

```
$ javac -classpath ./libs/*.jar server.java
```

Also, please do consider the possibility of using an IDE (such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org)) to compile your code samples. It will make your life way simpler than compiling everything by hand. You can just add all jWebSocket libraries to your project and compile your code sample. No need to deal with *classpath* issues manually.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. I tried that, but got the following error:

javac: invalid flag: ./libs/javolution-5.5.1.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Also, I'm not an IDE fan...